# angular material 2 - autocomplete não funciona

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

Estou com um problema, o auto complete do Angular Material não funciona no meu código. Ao carregar a página não chega a aparecer nem as opções.

***html***

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-6 form-md-line-input" style="margin-top:0px;">
    <input matInput formControlName="devedor" type="text" class="form-control" id="form_control_4" [matAutocomplete]="auto" (input)="getDevedor()">
    <!-- <i class="fa fa-spinner"></i> -->
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
            {{option}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
    <label for="form_control_4">Ente devedor</label>
</div>
```

***typescript***

```
export class FiltroComponent implements OnInit {

  options: string[] = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;

ngOnInit() {
  // AutoComplete Devedor
  this.filteredOptions = this.rForm.get("devedor").valueChanges
    .pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this._filter(value))
    );
  // End Of AutoComplete Tribunal

}

private _filter(value: string): string[] {
  const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

  return this.options.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
 }
```

Na minha visão está igual ao da documentação do Angualr Material, não faço ideia do por que não estar funcionando

Comment: como vc inicializa seu rForm? E como ele ta declarado no seu html?

Comment: `rForm: FormGroup;`

`<form class="form-body" [formGroup]="rForm" (ngSubmit)="sendBtn(rForm.value)">`

Comment: Digo no typexcript mesmo. como vc instancia ele?